# Highcharts x axis date grouping not working

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am facing one issue when using dynamically generated date array in x-axis category. At first, i tried with hard coded date values and it worked perfectly.
Below is my javaScript code snippet: -

```
var TempDates = [
  '2018-01-01',
  '2018-01-02',
  '2018-01-03',
  '2018-01-04',
  '2018-01-05',
  '2018-01-06',
  '2018-01-07',
  '2018-01-08',
  '2018-01-09',
  '2018-01-10',
  '2018-01-11',
  '2018-01-12',
  '2018-02-01',
  '2018-02-02',
  '2018-02-03',
  '2018-02-04',
  '2018-02-05',
  '2018-02-06',
  '2018-02-07',
  '2018-02-08',
  '2018-02-09',
  '2018-02-10',
  '2018-02-11',
  '2018-02-12',
  '2018-03-01',
  '2018-03-02',
  '2018-03-03',
  '2018-03-04',
  '2018-03-05',
  '2018-03-06'
    ];
var Dates = TempDates.map(function (date) {
        let formatOptions = { month: '2-digit', day: '2-digit', year: 'numeric' };
        return new Date(date).toLocaleDateString(undefined, formatOptions);
    });
```

The above code runs without giving any error. Now when i try to use array generated using Ajax call, then i face issue. Below given is the code which i used: -

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '@Url.Action("GetLastDates", "abc")',
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json",
        async: false,
        success: function (data) {
            for (var i in data) {
                TempDates1.push((data[i]));
            }
        }
    });

var Dates = TempDates1.map(function (date) {
    let formatOptions = { month: '2-digit', day: '2-digit', year: 'numeric' };
    return new Date(date).toLocaleDateString(undefined, formatOptions);
});
```

TempDates1 Output: -

```
["2018-09-04", "2018-09-05", "2018-09-06", "2018-09-07", "2018-09-08", "2018-09-09", "2018-09-10", "2018-09-11", "2018-09-12", "2018-09-13", "2018-09-14", "2018-09-15", "2018-09-16", "2018-09-17", "2018-09-18", "2018-09-19", "2018-09-20", "2018-09-21", "2018-09-22", "2018-09-23", "2018-09-24", "2018-09-25", "2018-09-26", "2018-09-27", "2018-09-28", "2018-09-29", "2018-09-30", "2018-10-01", "2018-10-02", "2018-10-03"]
```

Error: - "Uncaught RangeError: Invalid time value at Date.toISOString () at highcharts_date_range_grouping.min.js:1

Note: - I am using same date type as used in TempDates array.

Please help me as i am stuck with this for last 8 hours. There is some trick which i am unable to get.

Highchart code: -

```
Highcharts.chart('abc_Chart', {
        chart: {
            type: 'column'
        },
        dateRangeGrouping: {
            dayFormat: { month: 'numeric', day: 'numeric', year: 'numeric' }, weekFormat: { month: 'numeric', day: 'numeric', year: 'numeric' }, monthFormat: { month: 'numeric', year: 'numeric' }
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Total Message Count'
        },
        credits: {
            enabled: false
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: Dates
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Count'
            }
        },
        plotOptions: {
            column: {
                stacking: 'normal'
            }
        },
        tooltip: {
            formatter: function () {
                return '<b>' + this.x + '</b><br/>' +
                    this.series.name + ': ' + this.y + '<br/>' +
                    'Total: ' + this.point.stackTotal;
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Received',
            stack: 'Received',
            color: '#058DC7',
            data: [
              7.0, 6.0, 9.0, 14.0, 18.0, 21.0, 25.0, 26.0, 23.0, 18.0, 13.0, 9.0,
              3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 8.0, 11.0, 15.0, 17.0, 16.0, 14.0, 10.0, 6.0, 4.0,
              31.0, 43.0, 34.0, 22.0, 19.0, 11.0
            ],
        }, {
            name: 'Failure',
            stack: 'Sent',
            color: '#ff0000',
            data: [
             3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 8.0, 11.0, 15.0, 17.0, 16.0, 14.0, 10.0, 6.0, 4.0,
             7.0, 6.0, 9.0, 14.0, 18.0, 21.0, 25.0, 26.0, 23.0, 18.0, 13.0, 9.0,
             32.0, 53.0, 14.0, 27.0, 19.0, 14.0
            ],
            legendIndex: 1,
        },
         {
             name: 'Success',
             stack: 'Sent',
             color: '#50B432',
             data: [
               3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 8.0, 11.0, 15.0, 17.0, 16.0, 14.0, 10.0, 6.0, 4.0,
               7.0, 6.0, 9.0, 14.0, 18.0, 21.0, 25.0, 26.0, 23.0, 18.0, 13.0, 9.0,
               32.0, 53.0, 14.0, 27.0, 19.0, 14.0

             ],
             legendIndex: 0,
         }]
    });
```

Comment: what is the data that you receive from the call? can you show the content of the Dates array in later case?

Comment: I am getting last 30 days date in the same format as in previous case. Used small function for that. public string GetLastDates()
        {
            List<string> Dates = new List<string>();

            var lastSixMonths = Enumerable.Range(0, 30).Select(i => DateTime.Now.AddDays(i - 29)).Select(date => date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));
            foreach (string dt in lastSixMonths)
            {
                Dates.Add(dt);
            }

            string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Dates);
            return json;
        }

Comment: It would be easier, if you can generate the data and append it to the question in a formatted way. Then it should be possible to reproduce your issue.

Comment: I have added the output data.

Comment: I have understood one thing that why i am getting the error in later case. As the array doesn't consist of start date of the month which is present in earlier case. So, toLocaleDateString() is unable to format the array in the later case.

Answer (score 2):

I've tried your code in jsfiddle, and it does seem to work even with later data taht you've added.

I'd say that the problem is in the fact that ajax call is ansynchronous and your Dates array is not populated by the time when you render the chart. Try to rewrite your code in a way that constructs the chart after the data is loaded. Something like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '@Url.Action("GetLastDates", "abc")',
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json",
    async: false,
    success: function (data) {
        for (var i in data) {
            TempDates1.push((data[i]));
        }
        ctd(TempDates1);
    }
});

function ctd( data ){
    var Dates = data.map(function (date) {
        let formatOptions = { month: '2-digit', day: '2-digit', year: 'numeric' };
        return new Date(date).toLocaleDateString(undefined, formatOptions);
    });

    Highcharts.chart('abc_Chart', {
    chart: {
        type: 'column'
    },
    dateRangeGrouping: {
        dayFormat: { month: 'numeric', day: 'numeric', year: 'numeric' }, weekFormat: 
                   { month: 'numeric', day: 'numeric', year: 'numeric' }, monthFormat: { month: 'numeric', year: 'numeric' }
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Total Message Count'
    },
    credits: {
        enabled: false
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: Dates
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Count'
        }
    },
    plotOptions: {
        column: {
            stacking: 'normal'
        }
    },
    tooltip: {
        formatter: function () {
            return '<b>' + this.x + '</b><br/>' +
                this.series.name + ': ' + this.y + '<br/>' +
                'Total: ' + this.point.stackTotal;
        }
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Received',
        stack: 'Received',
        color: '#058DC7',
        data: [
          7.0, 6.0, 9.0, 14.0, 18.0, 21.0, 25.0, 26.0, 23.0, 18.0, 13.0, 9.0,
          3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 8.0, 11.0, 15.0, 17.0, 16.0, 14.0, 10.0, 6.0, 4.0,
          31.0, 43.0, 34.0, 22.0, 19.0, 11.0
        ],
    }, {
        name: 'Failure',
        stack: 'Sent',
        color: '#ff0000',
        data: [
         3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 8.0, 11.0, 15.0, 17.0, 16.0, 14.0, 10.0, 6.0, 4.0,
         7.0, 6.0, 9.0, 14.0, 18.0, 21.0, 25.0, 26.0, 23.0, 18.0, 13.0, 9.0,
         32.0, 53.0, 14.0, 27.0, 19.0, 14.0
        ],
        legendIndex: 1,
    },
     {
         name: 'Success',
         stack: 'Sent',
         color: '#50B432',
         data: [
           3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 8.0, 11.0, 15.0, 17.0, 16.0, 14.0, 10.0, 6.0, 4.0,
           7.0, 6.0, 9.0, 14.0, 18.0, 21.0, 25.0, 26.0, 23.0, 18.0, 13.0, 9.0,
           32.0, 53.0, 14.0, 27.0, 19.0, 14.0

         ],
         legendIndex: 0,
     }]
});
}
```